# trying to execute a query within a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that display another query I need to execute:

So the first part just writes out as text the first part of the query I want to execute

```
SELECT distinct 'SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM '
```

I then add on all the tables that I want to execute that initial part of the query on

```
table_name from all_tab_columns WHERE OWNER='RGSWKF_PRGM' AND COLUMN_NAME like '%TXN_ID%';
```

So my complete query is

```
SELECT distinct 'SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM ' || table_name from all_tab_columns WHERE OWNER='RGSWKF_PRGM' AND COLUMN_NAME like '%TXN_ID%';
```

This gives me a list of the queries I want to execute like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM MEETING_TXN_LIST
SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM TXN_COMMENT
SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM TXN_DEAL_FEE
```

....etc. I was told once I have this result I can auto execute the queries that are created as result of this by adding something to my original query but I can't find anything as of yet?

So basically I want it to execute from one query:

```
SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM MEETING_TXN_LIST
```

then

```
SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM TXN_COMMENT
```

then

```
SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM TXN_DEAL_FEE
```

etc. all in one query.

---

```
union
```

using union all with single quotes gives me the result with the text

```
SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM TXN_COMMENT union all ..etc...
```

Without the single quotes gives me the following error

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
```

Comment: Are you looking to make one great big query?  What do you want to do with these results?

Comment: @paqogomez yes I am looking to make one big query, please see my comment reply below on your answer

Comment: @paqogomez I have replied to your comment but for some reason I cant tag and mention your username on the comment section under your answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you generate a query with the subqueries connected by `union all`:

```
SELECT 'MEETING_TXN_LIST' as table_name, COUNT(txn_id) as cnt FROM MEETING_TXN_LIST UNION ALL
SELECT 'TXN_COMMENT', COUNT(txn_id) FROM TXN_COMMENT union all
SELECT 'TXN_DEAL_FEE' COUNT(txn_id) FROM TXN_DEAL_FEE;
```

The query for this is basically:

```
SELECT 'SELECT ''' || table_name || ''' as table_name, COUNT(txn_id) as cnt
        FROM ' || table_name || ' union all '
from all_tab_columns
WHERE OWNER = 'RGSWKF_PRGM' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'TXN_ID';
```

Note that you need to remove the final `union all` from the last row.  And, I changed the query to look only for the column `TXN_ID`, because that is what you are using in the queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select    txt
         || case
               when row_number() over (order by rn desc) = 1 then null
               else ul
            end
    from (select    'SELECT '''
                 || table_name
                 || ''' as table_name, COUNT(txn_id) as cnt FROM '
                 || table_name
                    as txt
                ,' union all ' ul
                ,rownum rn
            from all_tab_columns
           where OWNER = 'RGSWKF_PRGM' and COLUMN_NAME = 'TXN_ID')
order by rn
```